# Private static variable is accessible in different classes?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I declared a private static variable in one class. In the other file I could see them in the auto-complete. Is it some kind of a bug?

```
class Apple {
    private static var name = "Apple"
}
```

In different file,

```
class Steve {
    func call() {
        // I could autocomplete, but it is not accessible as it says no member with the name
        let name = Apple.name 
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift autocomplete feature is not that good yet. Doesn't always work as supposed to. And from time to time crashes.

Answer (score -1):

After compile you can see auto-complete.